# Unable to locate "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" when building a Windows binary using a Visual Studio 2013 generator

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake

I am currently in the beginning stages of learning how to develop on Windows using CMake, so I apologize in advance if these are dumb questions. I noticed that similar questions have been asked, but none have been able to help my issue.

I was provided a demo that I was asked to build on Windows, and this is a snippet of its `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 3.0)

SET (PROJECT_NAME "Demo")

IF (WIN32)
    IF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 10 2010")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc10_win32")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs10")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc10")
        SET (ARCH "Win32")
    ELSEIF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc10_x64")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs10")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc10")
        SET (ARCH "x64")
    ELSEIF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 11 2012")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc11_win32")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs11")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc11")
        SET (ARCH "Win32")
    ELSEIF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc11_x64")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs11")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc11")
        SET (ARCH "x64")
    ELSEIF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 12 2013")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc12_win32")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs12")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc12")
        SET (ARCH "Win32")
    ELSEIF (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} STREQUAL "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64")
        SET (PROJECT_SUFFIX "_vc12_x64")
        SET (VS_PLATFORM "vs12")
        SET (PLATFORM "vc12")
        SET (ARCH "x64")
    ELSE ()
        MESSAGE (FATAL_ERROR "Invalid or unsupported generator, CMake will exit.")
    ENDIF ()
ENDIF ()
```

Firstly, I installed `CMake` and set the necessary environment variable:

```
> cmake --version

cmake version 3.28.0-rc4
```

Next, I installed the necessary `MSBuild` tools:

```
> MSBuild /version

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

12.0.40629.0
```

Then I naively attempted to build the demo:

```
 > cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" ..

 CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
   Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of CMake.

   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (PROJECT):
   Failed to run MSBuild command:

     C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

   to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

     Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
     [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

     Build started 11/20/2023 9:33:54 AM.
     Project "Demo\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
     Demo\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
     Done Building Project "Demo\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

     Build FAILED.

     "Demo\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) -> Demo\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

         0 Warning(s)
         1 Error(s)

     Time Elapsed 00:00:00.26

   Exit code: 1

 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Its worth noting I didn't have Visual Studio 2013 installed at this point. However, after installing it, I was unable to find the mentioned `C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` anywhere in my various directories.

Can anyone lead me in the correct direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, after installing Visual Studio 2013 have you tried to configure your project again, with empty build directory?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, that's correct. I believe it has something to do with the missing "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" in my MSBuild / VS 2013 directories, but I'm not sure where they are.